# How to create exit button in Qt Design Studio(QML)

Tags: qt, qml

I use Qt Design Studio and i wanna create a exit icon in my app. I create button and use "Connections" to give him Qt.callLater(Qt.quit) but the problem is that i don't wanna rectangle button to exit, instead i wanna use cross image that is "close-512.png". But the problem is that i cannot hide the button silver color. It is cross on silver bar. I wanna to look like this: [Youtube 34 sec](https://youtu.be/QqERZr4Eb30?t=34) that also change background color when hover.

My code for now is that:

```
Button {
    id: exiter
    x: 395
    y: 8
    width: 58
    height: 50
    opacity: 1
    Image {
        id: cross
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 62
        height: 46
        source: "close-512.png"
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    visible: true
    clip: false
    checked: false
    checkable: false

    Connections {
        target: exiter
        onClicked: Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a background to the button.

```
Button {
    id: exiter
    x: 395
    y: 8
    width: 58
    height: 50
    opacity: 1
    Image {
    id: cross
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 62
    height: 46
    source: "close-512.png"
    fillMode: Image.Stretch
    anchors.fill: parent
    }
    visible: true
    clip: false
    checked: false
    checkable: false

    background: Rectangle {
        color: exiter.hovered ? 'darkgrey' : 'transparent'
    }

    Connections {
        target: exiter
        onClicked: Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
    }
}
```

The colors is now being handled by the line

```
color: exiter.hovered ? 'darkgrey' : 'transparent'
```

The darkgrey color shows when the button has been hovered, else the transparent color shows. So change them to suite you.

You can also use color code as

```
color: exiter.hovered ? '#e1e1e1' : 'transparent'
```